# Which reporting framework?

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, birt, dashboard

I have a web app, to which I need to add a web based dashboard, which will be updated periodically from a mysql database which aggregates the statistics to be viewed.

I'm looking for any easy to use and design framework, which will smoothly deploy into our web apps (in many different installations), which will look great, be free (or almost free).

Thought about BIRT, but I assume there are more up to date solutions. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Try bootstrap. Its neat with admin consoles and charts.